# preferrefstatusbarstyle not working in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3

> ```
>  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
> return .lightContent}
> ```

Using swift 3, I use setstatusbarstyle in my appdelegate and it works, but gives me warning that its deprecated starting ios 9.So am using this in my view controller, and its not working.I printed since the method as well, and it did not print.

Comment: Did you call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in the `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `View controller-based status bar appearance` bool to `No` in your plist file. And then in `General Settings` of your target `Status bar style` to `Light`.

Comment: yeh it works, however it says its depcreated since ios 9.0.Thats why I was trying it in my viewcontroller with preferredStatusBarStyle.

Comment: okey. but edit your answer to   
Add View controller-based status bar appearance bool to No in your plist file. And then in General Settings of your target Status bar style to Light. and remove the other answer.

Comment: There you go. Thanks!